# Why does requesting some permissions reject instantly with no dialog, while others do ask?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-automotive

On a blank/wiped AVD (AAOS), I have list of permissions that I need to be accepted.
When I try this, currently only `CAR_SPEED` is granted (should I accept) and all others are rejected with no dialog box and no indication in settings that they were ever requested.

For example: `android.car.permission.CAR_SPEED` and `android.car.permission.CAR_MILEAGE`.
When I request these 2 using `androidx.car.app.CarContext.requestPermisions`, I get a dialog box asking for location access permission (`android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.LOCATION"` for `android.car.permission.CAR_SPEED`). **Speed is accepted but mileage is not.** Note: mileage does not state itself to be in any group. The permissions are set up in the same way in

Only location permission request shows up in the app's settings. If I request these again, nothing is asked. **It fails silently** and the listener shows all of the other permissions (car mileage in this example) rejected.

Why is the behavior different and how can I ensure that all of the permissions are asked for **instead of being instantly rejected?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In Android, different permissions have different protection levels. Here's a [list](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/master/service/AndroidManifest.xml) of some of these. You can CTRL+F to find the permission you are looking for.

This can affect their behavior when they are requested at runtime.

For `android.car.permission.CAR_MILEAGE`, the protection level is `signature|privileged`

Per [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element), the `signature` base permission type is defined as follows:

> A permission that the system grants only if the requesting application is signed with the same certificate as the application that declared the permission. If the certificates match, the system automatically grants the permission without notifying the user or asking for the user's explicit approval.

By definition, the protection level of this permission means *it will never prompt or notify the user*. Google states that this is because these permissions are best not handled by the user.

The `privileged` protection level means that system apps are not subject to the above, and obtain it automatically.

Assuming you don't want to/don't have the means to make it a system app (usually you do not), and it is silently failing as opposed to silently succeeding, ensure the following:

1. Check that the permission is declared first in AndroidManifest.xml before requesting it, and
2. Make sure that the requesting app and the declaring app are signed with the same signing key. If they are the same app, they will be.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not really sure about a requesting/declaring app but I did add a keystore and key for release/debug. I'm just running AAOS on an AVD in Android Studio currently. AndroidManifest.xml is setup correctly I believe, just stating the name of the requested permission.